# Showing every finite rank n vector bundle over the affine line is trivial of rank n

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Ravi Vakil's algebraic geometry notes, exercise 13.2.C asks to show that every finite rank n vector bundle over $X = \mathbb{A}^1_k$ is actually free of rank n. The hint is to use the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PIDs.

My question is how to show that the vector bundle being *locally* free implies it is globally finitely generated.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be our vector bundle. If $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is finitely generated the structure theorem implies it's free, and clearly when we restrict down to one of our open sets over which is was free of rank n the ranks must agree.

But why is it finitely generated? Is it simply because if it were not I could construct a submodule of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ of rank greater than n? i.e. by choosing linearly independent elements.

Comment: Over affine varieties, all quasi-coherent sheaves are globally generated.

Comment: Oh, right. I can answer it now, thanks.

Comment: @Mohan What is a vector bundle on a scheme? Schemes aren’t manifolds.

Comment: @user46372819. Vector bundles can be defined even over topological spaces, manifold is not necessary.

Comment: @Mohan In the affine line case, what is the field that the vector spaces are defined over?

Comment: @Mohan Is it just $\mathbb R$? In the post, it says $\mathcal F$ is our vector bundle and then $\mathcal F(X)$ is finitely generated. But then what is $\mathcal F(X)$?

Comment: @user46372819 $F(X)$ is the set of sections of the vector bundle.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to showing that given a Noetherian ring A, an A-module M, and a finite open cover of SpecA by sets $D(f_i)$ along with the fact $M_{f_i}$ is Noetherian, then M is Noetherian, but this is a standard result.

Comment: Dear Garnet, could you tell me a reference? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @BenicioLima, sorry for the late response. We really want to show that M is finitely generated, because then we're finitely generated over a Noetherian ring, hence Noetherian. The argument is similar to that given in 5.3.9 of Ravi Vakil's notes, albeit with a module so you'll need to be a bit careful. You can find them here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf

I'll try and look up a more direct reference once I have access to my textbooks tomorrow. I think Hartshorne might cover this.